# Prove that any finite subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem:
Prove that a set of vectors $S$ is linearly independent if and only if any finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent.

I tried like this:

Suppose S is LI.Then the vector $0$ cannot be expressed as a linear sum of all elements of $S$.

How it follows that a finite subset is also LI from this fact.
I think $S$ can be finite or infinite.

This is a question from the book Linear Algebra - Friedberg et al.

Comment: Well, you haven't even attempted one half of the problem.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I have started with the only if part.

Comment: Is it necessary to use _all_ elements of $S$ when creating the linear sum that is not supposed to be $0$? If $S=\{x,y\}$, is a linear sum $ax+by$ or must is be $x+y$ only? If the former, can I take $a=b=0$? How about $a=0, b\neq 0$ or vice versa?

Comment: @DilipSarwate linear sum $ax+by$ is possible.

Comment: See https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_1-5-16?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** State what it means for a set of (possibly infinite) vectors to be linearly independent

**Hint:** Vector addition is done on a finite set. The idea of convergence of infinite sums requires an inherent topology which may not be present.

Answer (score 1):

A set $S$ being linearly independent by definition means no non-trivial linear combination of elements in $S$ is zero. And a linear combination is a FINITE sum.Therefore if all finite subsets are LI, $S$ is LI.